# Stop scrollview height from filling whole screen

Tags: android, scrollview

I am using a scrollview for my linear layout and i wondered if it was possible to stop the srollview height from occupying the whole screen like they way it is implemented in most twitter apps and instagram

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="289dp"
        android:layout_height="73dp"
        android:src="@drawable/identikatlogo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/first" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text|textCapWords" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLastName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/last" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/LastName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text|textCapWords" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEmail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/email" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Email"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text|textEmailAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAddress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/address" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Address"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCity"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/city" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/City"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text|textCapWords" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvState"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/state" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/State"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text|textCapWords" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvZip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/zipcode" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Zip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Submit"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/submit" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: please post the code for your layout

Answer (score 0):

Of course it takes the whole screen because you have provided the height of the scrollview to be fillparent here,

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >
```

If you need it to occupy only a portion then either you must try providing the height in some dip value or use linear layouts and provide weight sum for your layouts.